# Displaying keys and values of a nested hashmap in <rich:dataTable> (JSF 2.1, RichFaces 4.5.9)

Tags: jsf, hashmap, richfaces

In my bean I have a Hashmap that looks like this:

```
public HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>
```

I want to access the keys and values of the nested HashMap in a rich:dataTable component. I know that jsf components don't work well with hashmaps, but for a normal hashmap you can use a workaround to access keys and values like so:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.map.entrySet().toArray()}" var="entry">
        <h:outputText value="Key: #{entry.key}, Value: #{entry.value}"/>
</rich:dataTable>
```

However, I can not get this to work with my nested hashmap.

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{bean.map.entrySet().toArray()}" var="entry">
    <rich:dataTable value="#{entry.value.entrySet().toArray()}" var="nestedmap">
        <h:outputText value="Key: #{nestedmap.key}, Value: #{nestedmap.value}"/>
    </rich:dataTable>
</a4j:repeat>
```

Neither the key nor the value will show. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't have any columns in the table so there's nothing to show.

Comment: @Makhiel Thank you, that was indeed the problem. The code does work with that included.